# Syntax Error on the Python if statement

Tags: python

```
Data = 80
età = input('Per iniziare dimmi quanti anni hai:')
Data = Data - età
fumo = eval(input('Fumi? (si/no)')
 if fumo == 'si':
    Data = Data - 10
 else:
    pass
print('Ti restano da vivere ' Data 'anni')
```

I can't get where the error is, every time i run this i get syntax error on the colon at the end of the "if" line
I've red every post on the if else elif statements in python but still can't get why.

Comment: You have an error on eta variable... it could not go on with the tick:   eta = input('Per iniziare dimmi quanti anni hai:')

Comment: @DanielSanchez: it looks like the OP is using Python 3, in which case Unicode identifiers are permitted.

Comment: @DSM, ok I actually didnt know about it, thanks for the info!!! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
fumo = eval(input('Fumi? (si/no)')
```

Right there. You're missing a parenthesis at the end of this line. The open parenthesis makes Python think your `if` statement is actually part of this statement.

Comment: I would drop the eval() instead of fix it. It has a side effect (evaluates anything that is typed as Python source code) that is totally unneeded for the code that was posted.

Comment: While this is true as it goes, it might be worthwhile pointing out that this line is going to raise a NameError at runtime if the user actually enters `no` and not `"no"`.

Comment: Yeah, if using Python 2.x this should really be `raw_input` rather than `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a parenthesis at the end of your `fumo = eval(input('Fumi? (si/no)')` line.

Also, do not indent your is/else block.

```
Data = 80
età = input('Per iniziare dimmi quanti anni hai:')
Data = Data - età
fumo = eval(input('Fumi? (si/no)'))
if fumo == 'si':
    Data = Data - 10
else:
    pass
print('Ti restano da vivere', Data, 'anni')
```

**EDIT:**

I've also modified your printing line. You need to either separate each part that you want to print with commas, or concatenate them like so:

```
print('Ti restano da vivere ' + str(Data) + ' anni')
```

Comment: Since the OP is a beginner, we should probably point out that the last line won't work either.